# Using CATransform3DRotate with perspective: how to correct the 2D size increase?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, perspectivecamera, catransform3d

I'm trying to create a paper folding effect in Swift using CALayers and CATransform3DRotate. There are some libraries out there, but those are pretty outdated and don't fit my needs (they don't have symmetric folds, for example).
My content view controller will squeeze to the right half side of the screen, revealing the menu at the left side.

Everything went well, until I applied perspective: then the dimensions I calculate are not correct anymore.

To explain the problem, I created a demo to show you what I'm doing.
This the content view controller with three squares. I will use three folds, so each square will be on a separate fold.
The even folds will get anchor point (0, 0.5) and the odd folds will get anchor point (1, 0.5), plus they'll receive a shadow.

[image]

When fully folded, the content view will be half of the screen's width.
On an iPhone 7, each fold/plane will be 125 points unfolded and 62.5 points fully folded when looked at.
To calculate the rotation needed to achieve this 62.5 points width, we can use [a trigonometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_in_trigonometry). To illustrate, look at this top-down view:

[image: Top-down view of the planes]

We know the original plane size (125) and the 2D width (62.5), so we can calculate the angle α using arccos:

`let angle = acos(width / originalWidth)`

The result is 1.04719755 rad or 60 degrees.

When using this formula with CATransform3DRotate, I get the correct result:

[image: Correct result without perspective]

Now for the problem: when I add perspective, my calculation isn't correct anymore. The planes are bigger. Probably because of the now different projection.
You can see the planes are now overlapping and being clipped.
I reconstructed the desired result on the right by playing with the angle, but the correction needed is not consistent, unfortunately.

[image: Result and desired result with perspective]

Here's the code I use. It works perfectly without perspective.

```
// Loop layers
for i in 0..<self.layers.count {
    // Get layer
    let layer = self.layers[i]

    // Get dimensions
    let width = self.frame.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfFolds)
    let originalWidth = self.sourceView.frame.size.width / CGFloat(self.numberOfFolds)

    // Calculate angle
    let angle = acos(width / originalWidth)

    // Set transform
    layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    layer.transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500
    layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(layer.transform, angle * (i % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1), 0, 1, 0)

    // Update position
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        layer.position = CGPoint(x: (width * CGFloat(i)), y: layer.position.y)
    } else {
        layer.position = CGPoint(x: (width * CGFloat(i + 1)), y: layer.position.y)
    }
}
```

So my question is: how do I achieve the desired result? Do I need to correct the angle, or should I calculate the projected/2D width differently?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem yet?